# Install4j and Control Panel details

Tags: install4j

I'm looking at the Install4j "Register Add/Remove Item" action and how it affects what appears in the Windows Control Panel Programs area.  I'm having a problem with the "Version" that appears in the Control Panel - it doesn't match what I *want* displayed there, and I can't seem to figure out where that's configured.

I use compiler variables to store the product name and product version.  These variables are set in the media file area under "Customize Project Defaults/Compiler Variables"

Under "General Settings/Application info" in I4J, I use "${compiler:product-name}" for "Full Name" and "${compiler:product-version}" for "Version".  These are both properly set in the media file.

In the "Register Add/Remove Item" action, "Item Name" field, I use "${compiler:product-name} ${compiler:product-version}".

This appears correctly in control panel as the name (Sorry - I had to redact them for posting).  However, the version that appears in Control Panel does not appear the way that I want.

[image: Control Panel]

I don't see a "Product Version" field on the "Register Add/Remove Item" field, and it doesn't seem to be using the "Application Info" version either.  As a matter of fact, the "6.0.48" that appears under the "Version" column in the Control Panel doesn't appear anywhere in my "*project*.install4j" file.

How do I properly set that version, or where is it coming from?  Is it *supposed* to be using "Version" from "General Settings/Application Info"?  If so, is that not working as expected?

Thanks for any info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Register Add/Remove item" action uses the value from the "General Settings->Application Info" step, so in your case the resolved value of `${compiler:product-version}`.

If this is not the expected version, maybe it's from an older installation. You can check

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[application ID]
```

in the windows registry and delete keys there if required.

Comment: Ingo- thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working that way for me.  I reinstalled on a fresh VM image and am still getting the "6.0.48"  And searching for "6.0.48" in our install4j file shows absolutely nothing.  I can screenshot our AppID page, and the media file page where we set that variable if that will help.  I'm also getting the "6.0.48" on the title bar of the installer screens.  I'm stumped.

Comment: As a follow up, I use the version in the "Register Add/Remove Item" in the *Name* field like so:
"${compiler:product-name} ${compiler:installer-product-version}"

The version number (in the NAME field) shows up properly.  On my "Application info" page, my "Version" field is:
"${compiler:installer-product-version}"
Same compiler variable, but shows up wrong in the "Version" field of the Control Panel, as well as in the title bar on the installer windows.

Just adding this in case it helps....

Comment: Latest try: on the "Application info" page, changed my "Version" field to: "${compiler:sys.version}".  Same result.  Where do the "sys" variables get set?

Comment: I think I got it (testing now).  We're using ant's install4j task, and there was a "release" option being passed in (with the build number that I've been seeing) which was overriding the "Application Info->Version" value.  Thanks for your help, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't think of that either